# How do I use a list for SQL query values?

Tags: python, mysql

Instead of enumerating the items in a list in this scenario:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (url, date, " + column_headers + "total_keywords" + ")" \
                    "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                    (response.url,
                    datetime.date.today(),
                    some_list[0],
                    some_list[1],
                    some_list[2],
                    some_list[3],
                    ...
                    some_list[n]
                    )
                    )
```

I would like to pass num_keywords through more generally. Is it possible to use a list in an SQL query specifically in the VALUES part of the query?

The following code snippet does not work, but this is the idea:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (url, date, " + column_headers + "total_keywords" + ")" \
                    "VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                    (response.url,
                    datetime.date.today(),
                    some_list
                    )
                    )
```

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: Concatenating strings with `+` is a potential SQL injection issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*` operator to spread the list.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (url, date, " + column_headers + "total_keywords" + ")" \
                    "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                (response.url, datetime.date.today(), *list)
)
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it will replace the built-in class with that name.